# Do Windows 8 Metro style application support SQL Server CE local database?

Tags: database, windows-8, sql-server-ce, windows-store-apps

I have built a Windows Phone Application using SQL Server CE database.

We need transplant this app to Windows 8 Metro Style.

Do Windows 8 Metro-style applications support SQL Server CE local databases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already answered by ErikEJ, there is no native support for a local SQL Server CE database, but maybe this third party component SQLite is usefull for you?

Tim Heuer has wrote a blogpost about how to use SQLite in a metro style app:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx

In the blogpost there is also a video with the "How to" steps to use SQLite in your app.

Comment: Is SQLite supported by the ARM version of Windows RT, I saw the downloads on the SQLite website but there were only a 64bit and 32bit versions for intel, not ARM.

Comment: Don't know that, but I can imagine that they haven't had to chance to test/update it to work on ARM because there isn't an ARM Windows 8 version available.

Answer (score 4):

No, currently Microsoft does not provide a local database for Metro applications with C# and XAML.

Answer (score 3):

Not only can you not connect to a local SQL database, you can't connect to a remote one either.  Everything has to go through web services... or use SQLite.