# getting data from database in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, adomd.net

I am building a windows 8 app which requires me to get data from a remotely hosted server. Which API can I use to get the required data? I am using c# and xaml. I basically want to communicate with Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services. ADOMD.NET cannot be used as windows 8 store apps donot support it.

Comment: More information is required to help. What database application are you using? We also need to know if we are talking local or remote databases. There are limited options for a local database within a Windows Store application.  This question talks about your options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909202/do-windows-8-metro-style-application-support-sql-server-ce-local-database

Comment: the database is olap database. Its remote.

Answer (score 6):

In a Windows 8 app, we can specify for example a connection string to read out data stored in a server-side database. Not only would this be a huge security risk (imagine your connection string being on the thousands of devices where your app is downloaded!), it would also be pretty useless to have it there. WinRT has no knowledge of talking with a (remote) database. This means no ADO.NET or LINQ-To-SQL classes are in the API.

windows 8 style apps dont have out of the box functionality to contact to a database. so you need webservices to conect at a remote database.

If you have a database on a web server for which you can write an OData service, then that's an option. You can use the OData Libraries

I hope http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2012/04/26/developing-windows-8-metro-style-applications-that-consume-odata.aspx will help you.

Comment: thanx :) can odata be used for olap cubes or just simple relational data?

Comment: @Bunny - Try it for olap cubes and report your findings.

Comment: @Ramhound Is there a standard interface for publishing an MDX query up to SSAS from any client tool, and then be able to consume it via OData?